# Upgrading 18.04.5 to 20.04 LTS also upgrades postgresql?

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, 20.04, postgresql, do-release-upgrade

I'm doing `do-release-upgrade` now, and it seems it downloaded postgresql-12 package '__') was it automatically done? because I saw there's a tutorial to upgrade manually postgresql-10 to postgresql-12 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60409585/how-to-upgrade-postgresql-database-from-10-to-12-without-losing-data-for-openpro)

**UPDATE**

so I've done the `do-release-upgrade` and both version runs (postgresql 12 on different port), then I did the data migration steps on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61208581/1620210) still running (not yet completed) about 3.25 hours for 51GB of data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you do an upgrade of the ubuntu OS version, many other packages are also updated

you can see the version of the postgresql package in each ubuntu release here : https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=postgresql

at this moment : 18.04 -> postgres 10 & 20.04 : postgres 12

[image]

Comment: so would it do automatic migration '__')?

Comment: I'm not sure but I suspect it just upgrades the software and leaves the db as is - the release notes for 20.04 don't mention a data migration https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes#PostgreSQL_12

Comment: @Kokizzu no, you end up with both the old and new servers installed, and must migrate the data manually.

Answer (score 2):

Let's teach you how to use the `rmadison` script, included in the `devscripts` package.

It queries the Ubuntu repositories for the current versions of a package in each release of Ubuntu. This is the same information that's shown on the http://packages.ubuntu.com website...but may be faster for folks who need to check frequently.

Let's try it on `postgresql`

```
$ rmadison postgresql
 postgresql | 9.1+129          | precise         | all
 postgresql | 9.1+129ubuntu1   | precise-updates | all
 postgresql | 9.3+154          | trusty          | all
 postgresql | 9.3+154ubuntu1.1 | trusty-security | all
 postgresql | 9.3+154ubuntu1.1 | trusty-updates  | all
 postgresql | 9.5+173          | xenial          | all
 postgresql | 9.5+173ubuntu0.3 | xenial-security | all
 postgresql | 9.5+173ubuntu0.3 | xenial-updates  | all
 postgresql | 10+190           | bionic          | all
 postgresql | 10+190ubuntu0.1  | bionic-security | all
 postgresql | 10+190ubuntu0.1  | bionic-updates  | all
 postgresql | 12+214           | focal           | all
 postgresql | 12+214ubuntu0.1  | focal-security  | all
 postgresql | 12+214ubuntu0.1  | focal-updates   | all
 postgresql | 12+216           | groovy          | all
 postgresql | 13+223           | hirsute         | all
```

The output tells us that:

- Ubuntu 18.04 uses postgresql 10 (10+190ubuntu0.1)
- Ubuntu 20.04 uses postgresql 12 (12+214ubuntu0.1)

This means that a `do-release-upgrade` from 18.04 to 20.04 of the `postgresql` package will indeed migrate you from version 10 to version 12 automatically.

Look at the last two lines of output: A do-release-upgrade from Groovy (20.10) to Hirsute (21.04) will migrate you from version 12 to version 13.

Comment: tried it just now, it doesn't migrate the data ^^) it running both version

Comment: It's impossible, using the `postgreql` package, to install both simultaneously. This suggests that you used some other method to install one of the versions...and therefore that you were apparently asking the wrong question, or provided incomplete information.

Comment: that's what happened, i'm running the migration manually https://stackoverflow.com/a/61208581/1620210

Comment: @user535733 the `postgresql` package doesn't contain anything, the actual packages (which can be installed side-by-side) are `postgresql-10` and `postgresql-12`

Comment: @OrangeDog correct, and important for the OP to know. Since we NOW know that the OP (unwisely) followed random online advice and (apparently) installed *both* -10 and the metapackage, having both -10 and -12 installed is indeed expected behavior.

Comment: @user535733 that's exactly what you want to do. That's how you do a migration.

Comment: @OrangeDog seems like you have a good answer there. Feel free to add it!